# can I fake Request.IsLocal to be true for in office colleagues?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, http, iis

I'd like to give colleagues in the office the ability to view my local VisualStudio build of our solution. I view it via a hosts file edit for 127.0.0.1 site.com

I've setup their hosts files to point site.com to MY internal IP address, and they bring up the site fine, the problem is that we have a lot of checks site-wide for if(Request.IsLocal) that decides what versions of JS and CSS files to display, and as such they're not seeing what they're supposed to see. (because they're not the localhost viewing the site)

There's a lot of avenues I could go with dealing with this I know, but I'm hoping someone knows of a way to fake/force the Request.IsLocal to pass if I want it to. My first thought was some trick in my local IIS site bindings, and I'm currently investigating that avenue but haven't come up with anything yet.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - there is no way to fake/fool `Request.IsLocal` (at least not without hacking some .NET internals which I do NOT recommend).

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use IIS or IIS Express ? IIS express is also freely available from MS, and can be enabled for external requests http://blogs.iis.net/vaidyg/archive/2010/07/29/serving-external-traffic-with-webmatrix-beta.aspx

Comment: I do use IIS, I'm open to any IIS resolutions to my problem

Comment: that doesn't help since inside the code the OP has `if (Request.IsLocal)` which is only true when the rquest comes from a loopback address...

Comment: sorry, i had not seen the if(Request.IsLocal) is a part of the code .... in that case, install a simple proxy tool such as tcptrace081 .... configure tcptrace081 to listen on port 8081, and redirect all traffic to 80. Configure IIS to listen on port 80. Ask your colleagues to connect to your machine port 8081

Comment: @SachinNayak thanks for that suggestion! I'll google tcptrace081 and get back to you in about an hour with my results